# Vue3 Dynamic Component Return Props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dynamic, vue-component, reactive

Messing around with Vue3's Dynamic Component `<component>`, and I have this current setup:

**Component 1:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1> Input name: </h2>
    <Input :model="props.name" />
    <p> {{props.example}} </p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default{
  props:["props"]
}
</script>
```

**Main File**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <component :is='active.page' :props='active.props' />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import UserName from 'components/UserName.vue'
export default{
  components: { UserName }
  setup() {
    const active = { page: 'UserName', props: { name: null, example: 'Dave' } }

    return {active}
  }
}
```

Eventually, there will be multiple pages that the user can navigate through using a `<Button />` of sorts; the question is:
Is it possible to return the prop `name` back to the **Main File** after it has been modified inside **Component 1**?

The reason is that it needs to be passed to the next pages within `<component>` for display when the user presses next

Thanks for the assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `emit` to pass the name back to the `Main File` and **do not modify the props directly**, declare another variable to store it and modify this variable.

```js
// Component 1
<template>
  <div>
    <h1> Input name: </h1>
    <Input v-model="name" />
    <p> {{props.example}} </p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { defineEmits } from 'vue'
export default {
  props:["props"],
  emits: ['name-updated'],
  data() {
    return {
      name: this.props.name
    }
  },
  watch: {
    name() {
      this.$emit('name-updated', this.name)
    }
  }
}
</script>

// Main File
<template>
  <div>
    <component :is='active.page' :props='active.props' @name-updated="updateName" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import UserName from 'components/UserName.vue'
export default{
  components: { UserName },
  setup() {
    const active = { page: 'UserName', props: { name: null, example: 'Dave' } }
    const updateName = (newName) => {
      active.props.name = newName
    }
    return {active, updateName}
  }
}  
</script>
```

Comment: Works, but receiving the error `Extraneous non-emits event listeners (nameUpdated) were passed to component... (etc.)`?
Also, `defineEmits` was never utilized?

Comment: sorry, when `emits` is used outside the `setup`,  `defineEmits ` is not necessary. when used in, the `emits` should be used like this `const emits = defineEmits(['name-updated'])`

Comment: I have one other question related to this: When <component @name-updated="updateName" /> receives the `newName`, how can I assign said name to other objects with the value `name` within the `active` array that ` component` uses? Using `foreEach` just returns a props value wrapped in multiple proxies that cannot be accessed